# how to debug a website on your mobile phone through desktop chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, android, emulator, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently working on creating a responsive website.. and it looks funny on my nexus 5 (chrome app).. I've tried using the chrome dev tools emulator (as well as other websites) but the proposed output seems different than what i actually see on my phone.. is there a way to debug what shows up on my phone on chrome dev tools on my desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome recently released [Remote Debugging on Android](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) as part of the Chrome Web Developer Tools on the desktop browser.

To summarize:

1. Enable USB debugging on your Android device
2. Enable USB discovery in Chrome
3. Connect your device via USB
4. Debug